# Melhor maneira de selecionar uma coluna especifica que esta dentro de uma function ($query)

Tags: php, laravel

Possuo uma consulta onde tenho vários relacionamentos entre tabelas diferentes, qual seria a melhor maneira de selecionar uma coluna especifica que esta dentro da `Function($query)`
nesse caso se aplica a regra de  `->where('produtos.id','=',$id)`

e quero chegar ao resultado onde eu seleciona tudo a partir do id da tabela variacao ao invez da tabela produto como esta atualmente no codigo. por exemplo:

```
->where('variacao.id','=',$id)

public function buscarPorId($id)
{
  //$id_admin = Credencial::recuperarIdAdmin();
   return $this->produto->with('descricao')
   ->with('produtoMarketplace')
   ->with(['produtoCategoria' => function ($query) {
         $query->Join('categoria', 'categoria.id', '=', 'produto_categoria.id_categoria')
          ->Join('departamento', 'departamento.id', '=', 'categoria.id_departamento');
         }
      ]) 
   ->with([
        'variacao' => function ($query) {
            $query->Join('atributo', 'atributo.variacao_id', '=', 'variacao.id')
                ->Join('valor_atributo', 'valor_atributo.id', '=', 'atributo.valor_atributo_id')
                ->Join('item_atributo', 'item_atributo.id', '=', 'valor_atributo.tipo_atributo_id');
        }
    ])
        ->where('produtos.id','=',$id)
      ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de analisar melhor o select, consegui encontrar uma maneira de resolver o problema, e fazer a consulta da maneira esperada.

O codigo ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
  public function buscarPorId($id){
   return $this->produto->with('descricao')
   ->with('produtoMarketplace')
   ->with(['produtoCategoria' => function ($query) {
         $query->Join('categoria', 'categoria.id', '=', 'produto_categoria.id_categoria')
          ->Join('departamento', 'departamento.id', '=', 'categoria.id_departamento');
         }
      ]) 
   ->with([
        'variacao' => function ($query) use($id) {
         $query->Join('atributo', 'atributo.variacao_id', '=', 'variacao.id')
             ->Join('valor_atributo', 'valor_atributo.id', '=', 'atributo.valor_atributo_id')
             ->Join('item_atributo', 'item_atributo.id', '=', 'valor_atributo.tipo_atributo_id')
             ->where('sku', $id);
       } 
     ])->whereHas('variacao', function($q) use($id) {
         $q->where('sku', $id);
     })->get();
 }
```

Adicionando

```
->whereHas('variacao', function($q) use($id) {
             $q->where('sku', $id);
         })->get();
```

É possivel fazer a consulta a partir do $id da variavel que esta dentro de uma $query

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usando o [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects)

```
    public function buscarPorId($id)
{
  //$id_admin = Credencial::recuperarIdAdmin();
   return $this->produto->with('descricao')
   ->with('produtoMarketplace')
   ->with(['produtoCategoria' => function ($query) {
         $query->Join('categoria', 'categoria.id', '=', 'produto_categoria.id_categoria')
          ->Join('departamento', 'departamento.id', '=', 'categoria.id_departamento');
         }
      ]) 
   ->with([
        'variacao' => function ($query) {
            $query->Join('atributo', 'atributo.variacao_id', '=', 'variacao.id')
                ->Join('valor_atributo', 'valor_atributo.id', '=', 'atributo.valor_atributo_id')
                ->Join('item_atributo', 'item_atributo.id', '=', 'valor_atributo.tipo_atributo_id');
        }
    ])
        ->where('produtos.id','=',$id)
        // Aqui você define os campos que quer como resultado da consulta. 
        ->select('tabela_a.campo', 'tabela_b.campo') 
        ->get();
}
```